# Entity Relationship Diagram - Multiplicities

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, diagram

I have done a lot of reading into multiplicities for ER diagrams, and I believe I have an understanding of what each requirement is, but as someone self studying with the internet and a textbook, it is hard to see where I have made mistakes.

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cinema - There are multiple cinema complexes with their name, location and contact number list.

Theatres - There are 4 in each cinema. Two types are available and each one is identified by a screen number.

Seats - Many seats in each theatre are determined by the row number, seat number and the seat type (comfort level).

Purchase - Tickets are to be purchased at the cinema complex. This will include screening date, time and seat number.

Members - Members are defined by their name and email.

Signup - Many members sign up with or without a discount at the cinema of their choice.

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: Thank you Philipxy. I have a lot to review with my ERD and the fundamentals behind it before re-drawing this. It is a learning process step by step, but I will make sure to present the ERD in text for any future questions. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Per "The Entity-Relationship Model-Toward a Unified View of Data", Chen ERD lines between entity type boxes and relationship type diamonds denote participation of the entity type in the relationship type. There's no direction to the relationship type. There's an order to entity types in the a natural language (or wff) expression (or name) of the relationship type, but ERDs don't show that by an arrow. ("Has" is uninformative. You mean a kind of "Within", of which you have two, isSeatWithinTheatre & isTheatreWithinCinemaComplex.)

An arrow expresses "the existence dependency of one entity type on another".

Chen ERDs have one number (or range) per line. It gives "the number of entities in each entity set which is allowed in a relationship set".

PS Your ERD says a CinemaComplex has an associated Merchandise but presumably there should be a relationship CinemaComplexSellsMerchandise.

PPS Please represent your ERD in text in your question. Every box & diamond gets a table with PK, every box, oval & participant gets an attribute, every line gets a FK. Sadly, presentations of ERDs are typically vague about allowing relationship type attributes (rather than entities) as parts of PKs.

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer, if there wasn't the last PPS. An ERD expresses a design intent in a graphical way (the D stands for diagram). Tables with PK, FK and attributes are one particular implementation of the design (but there could be others). Moreover, the design intent must be reverse engineered from the (PK, FK) pairs whereas it's provided instantly with the graphical notation. In other words, replacing ERD with textual tables (and why not Sql statemnets then) get rid of the inteded level of abstraction the ERD was invented for

Comment: @Christophe It is trivial to give the design content of an ERD in text/DDL. Also a diagram should have a legend. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: The key in your reference question  is "I have uploaded images of my **code** on most of my questions" and in the accepted answer " and "You should not post code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, project files, or **anything else that is represented in textual form**) 1s an image".  These statements are agains screenshots of code or textual information. And I agree that this is terrible, when you have screenshots of c++ code or sql, that you simply could copy-paste if it where text. However this does not apply to non-code and in particular not to **graphical** notations such as ERD

Comment: As said, SQL or other DDL are not ERD nor UML. There are no standardized textual representztion, neither for ERD nor for UML. For these notations it is ok to show an image. Transforming to text is already an interpretation of the design and is no longer reliable transcript. It is however a good paractice to provide an alternate text for the image, so that visual impaired people ca get at least a description of the image for the reader.